# Measure input voltage of Raspberry Pi B+ running Ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, hardware

I just learned that [a red flashing LED indicates voltage below 4.63V](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/24674/31439) on a [Raspberry Pi Model B+](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/model-b-plus/).

Is there a command to determine the voltage programmatically?

I tried `vcgencmd measure_volts`. But it yields 1.2000V, independent of the input source and the LED status. And it doesn't seem to be related to the 4.63V mentioned above.

#### Update

Let me describe the situation in a bit more detail:

I'm powering the Raspberry Pi with a lead-acid battery built into a moving robot. After operating the robot for a while, the voltage seams to drop below a critical minimum, causing potential damage to the file system. Therefore, I'd like to detect low voltage automatically (and trigger the robot to return to the charging station).

I'm asking here in StackOverflow, since I assume the solution not to be robotic-specific, but generally applicable to other machines.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, as it is said in this topic [Under-voltage warnings](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=82373) you can know the low voltage reading the GPIO 35. For reading GPIO, you can refer to this topic:
[Python Script to read one pin](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=43069)

Comment: Good idea! At least, I successfully downloaded and installed the RPi.GPIO python module. But python (with sudo) exits as soon as I call `GPIO.setup(35, GPIO.IN)`. There isn't even an error message.

Comment: This answer helped me in a related context: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33544792/3419103

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the **adafruit ina219**  sensor https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-ina219-current-sensor-breakout.pdf .

This sensor can be put between the battery and the raspberry and measures the current and the voltage along this connection (0-26V and max. 3.2A). It communicates via i2c bus. Together with an Arduino you can easyly  build an battery watchdog for your raspberry. A sample program and the arduino driver can be found here: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_INA219.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7414/is-it-possible-to-detect-input-voltage-using-only-software it's not possible to do it on software level without other hardware.