# Raspberry PI 2 GPIO.setup() exits without any error

Tags: python, gpio, raspberry-pi2

I got a Pi2 and wanted to run the led example. But for some reason, the `GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)` always returns without any warnings or errors.

I run it in interactive mode with `sudo`, that's how I figured out it returned at the `setup()` function.

Can anybody help? Thanks in advance.

Here is the commands I run.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time                   

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)       ## neither BOARD  nor BCM  works.
GPIO.setup(11, GPIO.OUT)       ##<<<< it returns here without error.

GPIO.output(11, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, installing the beta version of RPi.GPIO fixed the problem.

```
sudo pip uninstall RPi.GPIO
sudo pip install hg+http://hg.code.sf.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/code#egg=RPi.GPIO
```

More info:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=113014&p=773725